# State restoration in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, state-restoration

I am trying to preserve and restore the state of a certain VC in my app, and so far have not been able to force quit the app and restore the state despite implementing (what I think) should do the trick. I've gone through the documentation and a few examples, but am still struggling to get the implementation to work. I set the restorationID in storyboard, and have all the necessary functions in `AppDelegate` here:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    // For non-scene-based versions of this app on iOS 13.1 and earlier.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        coder.encode(1.0, forKey: "version")
        return true
    }

    // For non-scene-based versions of this app on iOS 13.1 and earlier.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        let version = coder.decodeFloat(forKey: "version")
        if(version == 1.0) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.2, *)
    // For non-scene-based versions of this app on iOS 13.2 and later.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldSaveSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        coder.encode(1.0, forKey: "version")

        return true
    }
    
    @available(iOS 13.2, *)
    // For non-scene-based versions of this app on iOS 13.2 and later.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreSecureApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
        let version = coder.decodeFloat(forKey: "version")
        if(version == 1.0) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

and in my view controller:

```
extension CurrentSessionVC {
   
    override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
        
        coder.encode("Hello World", forKey: "message")
    }
    
    override func decodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
        super.decodeRestorableState(with: coder)
        
        let message = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "message") as! String
        print(message)
        
    }
}
```

I set some breakpoints to see what is going on, and when I multi task and clear the app, the breakpoint in `shouldSaveSecureApplicationState` triggers, then when I close the app, stop the program, and re run it the `shouldRestoreSecureApplicationState` function triggers, but the view controller is NOT restored. I've gone through and tested one of apples examples (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/restoring_your_app_s_state) and it works exactly how it should, you clear the app and next time you open the app it picks up where you left off. Am I completely missing something important?

Answer (score 0):

- Suspend the app by opening the Home screen on your iPhone simulator. You can swipe it up or use the shortcut: ‘Command (⌘) + Shift (⇧) + H’

!!! Do not kill the app manually by swiping it up from the multitasking menu. In this case, the system will delete all the state information.

- Stop the Xcode debugger by clicking on the "STOP" button or use the shortcut: ‘Command (⌘) + .’
- Rerun the app using Xcode